# Click with VBA web scraping

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I'm running a macro for web scraping and I got stuck when trying to click on the next element:

```
<a title="Buscar Pedidos (Ctrl+TeclConmut+P)" class="th-lk" id="C7_W35_V36_ZBUSCA_PED" onclick="htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'thtmlb:link:click:0','myFormId','C7_W35_V36_ZBUSCA_PED','ZBUSCA_PED',0);return false" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">Buscar Pedidos</a>
```

I've tried with
`odocument.getelementsbyclassname("th-lk").click`

or

`odocument.getelementsbytagbame("Buscar Pedidos (Ctrl+TeclConmut+P)").click`

and nothing works.

Even just calling the javascript function, but I don't know what I am missing.

If you could help me with this it would be amazing!

Comment: `getElementsByClassname` and `getElementsByTagName` each return a collection of elements.  So you would need to reference the desired one by index number, where the indexing starts at 0.  However, the element has an ID.  So you can  use `getElementByID` instead., for example `odocument.getElementById("C7_W35_V36_ZBUSCA_PED").click`

Comment: Side note: IE is deprecated and uninstalled even from professional environments, we're on "grace period". I'd highly suggest you try selenium

Comment: Doesn’t work either…